# Google Bar Chart Moving x-axis labels to Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization, bar-chart

I am using Google Bar Chart and i want to move the x-axis label to the top. I have written the code but its not happening. Please check the fiddle and screen shot.
Any suggestions?

Thanks,

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/n5paq0r9/`
```

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ox6O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.
.
.
.
after

```
chart.draw(data, options);
```

add this code

```
var height = options.height;
            var array = $("#chart_div svg g").children()[3].children;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                $("text").removeClass("currentNode");
                array[i].children[0].setAttribute("class", "currentNode");
                var y = height - parseFloat($(".currentNode").attr("y"));
                $(".currentNode").attr("y", y);
            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n5paq0r9/3/

Comment: you should wait on the `'ready'` [event](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#events) before modifying the chart -- charts with more data / take longer to draw, could result in an error otherwise...

Comment: @WhiteHat you are right but that happens in case of asynchronous ajax call, here `chart.draw(data, options)` uses synchronous call first complete this request, then go for other codes.

Comment: it wouldn't affect result :)

Answer (score 3):

[Top-X charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#top-x-charts) are available only for *Material* charts

*Material* Bar Chart
`google.charts.Bar`

vs. *Core* Bar Chart
`google.visualization.BarChart`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['App Name', 'Density', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' } ],
         ['My Test App Name Appears Here', 6.94, 'blue', 'My Test App Name Appears Here' ],
         ['My Test App Name Appears Here', 10.49, 'blue', 'My Test App Name Appears Here' ],
         ['My Test App Name Appears Here', 19.30, 'blue', 'My Test App Name Appears Here' ],
         ['My Test App Name Appears Here', 24, 'blue', 'My Test App Name Appears Here' ],
         ['My Test App Name Appears Here', 5.30, 'blue', 'My Test App Name Appears Here' ],
         ['My Test App Name Appears Here', 2.30, 'blue', 'My Test App Name Appears Here' ],
         ['My Test App Name Appears Here', 21.45, 'blue', 'My Test App Name Appears Here' ]
      ]);

var options = { 
          chartArea: {width: '90%'},
          height: 500,
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          vAxis:{textStyle:{color: '#005500',fontSize: '12', paddingRight: '100',marginRight: '100'}},
          hAxis:{textStyle:{color: '#005500',fontSize: '11', paddingRight: '100',marginRight: '100'}},
          bars: 'horizontal',
          axes: {             
            x: { 
              0: { side: 'top'} 
            }                     
          }     
        };

      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
    }
    
    
$(window).resize(function(){
  drawBasic();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. It is working fine but annotation seems to be not appearing in the chart? How can we add annotations to a Material Bar Chart ?

Comment: there are several options, including annotations, that simply don't work on _Material_ charts